# Angstrom symbol in Matlab

Tags: matlab, textbox, matlab-figure, tex

I would like to write `q=0.1 Å` inside a textbox in a plot that I have made using code. I am using Matlab. I have written the following:

```
str={'q=0.1$\AA$'};
annotation('textbox',...
[0.45 0.8 0.2 0.1],...
'interpreter','latex','string',str,...
'fontsize',20,...
'fontname','times new roman',...
'edgecolor','none',...
'fitboxtotext','on');
```

which yields:

[image: plot]

The problem is that the [angstrom symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom) it is producing is a bit weird. The circle at the top of the `A` is very off. I have tried other options for `'fontname'`, but the result is the same. Is there a way to get a proper angstrom symbol in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a LaTeX problem than a MATLAB problem. If you print `$\AA$` in a LaTeX document, it will look the same.

A workaround would be to remove the `$...$`, as you don't need a math environment for `\AA`:

```
str={'q=0.1\AA'};
annotation('textbox',...
[0.45 0.8 0.2 0.1],...
'interpreter','latex','string',str,...
'fontsize',20,...
'fontname','times new roman',...
'edgecolor','none',...
'fitboxtotext','on');
```

In my opinion, the result looks much better:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that in LaTeX math mode (between the `'$'` characters), most text defaults to italics. You can remedy this by changing your first line to use \textrm:

```
str={'q=0.1$\textrm{\AA}$'};
```

The output annotation string now looks like:

[image]

\rm will also work, but may be [deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151899). \mathrm also appears to work in this case, but apparently can do [more complicated font sunbstitutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22353). I would actually make the full string math in order to italicize `'q'` and get proper spacing around the `'='` sign:

```
str={'$q=0.1\textrm{\AA}$'};
```

See the difference:

[image]

Though, as @hbaderts points out, `str={'$q=0.1$\AA'};` would work too, but may yield slightly different kerning.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `$` around the `\AA`:

```
str = 'q=0.1\AA';
annotation('textbox', [0.45 0.8 0.2 0.1], 'interpreter','latex','string',str);
```

produce a straight angstrom sign, while `'$\AA$'` produce what you have.